# How to iterate through multiple folders and compare pdfs stored in it using Java

Tags: java, pdf

I am trying to compare PDF files stored in different folders one by one below is the code I wrote in it when using that when it compares the second PDF file(file 22)of folder (data) its taking the first PDF from the other folder to compare can any one help

````
String object ="D:\\test.pdf";
String data ="D:\\test2.pdf";

              Log.info("PDF Documents has been Verified");

             

              // boolean isEquals = false;

              try{

                     String result =Constants.Path_Result+DriverScript.s;

                      File[] file10 = new File(object).listFiles(File::isFile);

                     for (File file1: file10) {

                     String fileExtension = file1.getName().split("\\.")[file1.getName().split("\\.").length - 1];

                     if (fileExtension.toLowerCase().equals("pdf")) {

                      

                              file12 =file1.getAbsolutePath();

                               System.out.println(file12);

                    

             File[] file121 = new File(data).listFiles(File::isFile);

             for (File file2: file121) {

             String fileExtension1 = file2.getName().split("\\.")[file2.getName().split("\\.").length - 1];

                     if (fileExtension1.toLowerCase().equals("pdf")) {

                          

                             String file22 =file2.getAbsolutePath();

                              

                           new de.redsix.pdfcompare.PdfComparator(file12, file22).compare().writeTo(result+"//"+file2.getName());

                          

                     }}}}

                  }catch(Exception e){

                       System.out.println(e.getMessage());

              Log.error("Not able to Close the Browser --- " + e.getMessage());

              DriverScript.bResult = false;

                       }

              }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use the below java code it will work
(What i did was combined two of your for loop that you have written in to one so that both the folders will get iterated at the same time.)

```
String path1 = "D:\\newfolder\\";

String path2 = "D:\\newfolder1\\";

String result="D:\\result\\";

File folder1 = new File(path1);

File folder2 = new File(path2);         

File[] listOfFiles1 = folder1.listFiles();

File[] listOfFiles2 = folder2.listFiles();                  

ArrayList<String> fileNames1 = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> fileNames2 = new ArrayList<String>();                  

for ( int i = 0,j = 0; i < listOfFiles2.length&& j < listOfFiles1.length; i++,j++)

if (listOfFiles2[i].isFile()&&listOfFiles1[j].isFile())

{  fileNames2.add(listOfFiles2[i].getName().split("\\.")[listOfFiles2[i].getName().split("\\.").length - 1]);

   fileNames1.add(listOfFiles1[j].getName().split("\\.")[listOfFiles1[j].getName().split("\\.").length - 1]);                      

   String str = fileNames1.toString();

   str.toLowerCase().equals("pdf");          

  String file01 =listOfFiles1[j].getName();

   file12 =listOfFiles1[j].getAbsolutePath();

       String str1 = fileNames2.toString();

       str1.toLowerCase().equals("pdf");

    file0 =listOfFiles2[i].getName();

       file22 =listOfFiles2[i].getAbsolutePath();

      

    new de.redsix.pdfcompare.PdfComparator(file12,file22).compare().writeTo(result+"//"+file0);

 }
```

Comment: young man add tags to the question to get more reach... I think its java code, put java in tag line